# Glyphicons will not show up in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I can't get glyphicons to show up. Currently, a small square shows up instead of the glyphicon. I've tried moving folders, etc. I didn't do custom bootstrap - I just downloaded the whole thing, so there shouldn't be any errors/anything missing. Here's my code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
            <h2>Welcome!</h2>
            <p>
            </p>
        </div> <!-- heading div -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
            <div class="interests">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera">
                </span>
                <h4>People</h4>
            </div> <!-- interests divs -->
        </div> <!-- column divs -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

Am I missing something at the top that needs to be included to get the fonts to show up? In the head, I have a link to the bootstrap.min.css - should I be linking to anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing its's not showing for 2 possible reasons:
1. You have not installed the fonts
2. You have not added the font folder  hence bootstrap cannot load the glyphicons.

fonts----a folder containing fonts
css------a folder containing bootstrap css files.
index.html-----this file should link to the href="css/bootstrap.css" which intern calls the fonts files

Comment: I have the fonts folder with all the appropriate fonts. It's in the same folder with all of my files. Should it not be there? When I downloaded bootstrap, I got all of the normal files - dist folder that contains fonts, css, js.

Comment: and  are all the folders on the same level i.e  \css \fonts should be on the same level

Comment: No - they weren't. And now they are. And now it works. THANK YOU! I am completely new to all of this and am trying to clunk my way through. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You may check the following images (2 images).

[image: glyphicons-halflings.png]
[image: glyphicons-halflings-white.png]

Or, you can check those fonts.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/fonts

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand what you mean by checking them?

Comment: "checking them" means you can go and check those images or fonts in /fonts folder. sorry